# Keeping conditions in filenames in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have few logs files in `C:\temp\20120214.003_visual_sciences_web_feed.out.gz` file. The filenames created for these logfiles are named based on YYYMMDD format on the day they were created. Now I want to write a batch file, that retrieve log files for files that are created between 1-jan-2013 to 1-sep-2013.

I am new to batch file scripting. Based on filename I am thinking of loop through all the files, get the index of each and every filename from 1-6 and filter it to check date conditions (using BETWEEN date1 and date2).

How can I accomplish this using AND conditions in simple way or do we have any other way?

Comment: I believe you meant to say YYYYMMDD format (you are missing a Y)

Comment: yes sorry you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is tough to tell exactly what you want. But I believe this should be close:

From the command prompt (no batch):

```
for /f "delims=" %F in ('dir /b "c:\temp\*.out.gz"') do @if "%F" geq "20130101" if "%F" lss "20130902" @echo %F
```

From within a batch script:

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "c:\temp\*.out.gz"') do if "%%F" geq "20130101" if "%%F" lss "20130902" echo %%F
```

or formatted nicely:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "c:\temp\*.out.gz"') do (
  if "%%F" geq "20130101" if "%%F" lss "20130902" echo %%F
)
```

The above solutions will include files from 1-sep-2013. If you do not want to include that date, then change the last string to '"20130901"'.

Note that IF is doing a string comparison, not a date or numeric comparison. This only works because your date format is YYYYMMDD.

If you have additional `.out.gz` files that do not start with the date, and should therefore be ignored, then you can add a FINDSTR regex to be more selective. Unfortunately, FINDSTR regex support is very limited - there is no support for something like `[0-9]{8}`.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b "c:\temp\*.out.gz"^|findstr "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.'
) do if "%%F" geq "20130101" if "%%F" lss "20130902" echo %%F
```

Comment: Thanks it worked
Further ,I am trying to copy those files in to c:\temp4.
Similary I need to copy the similar matching files from c:\temp2 into c:\temp4
I am modifying the script as below but script is not working.
Please suggest 
@echo off
net use x: \\fwtgvs250win\f$ /user:srvvsbatchfiles *
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b "c:\temp2\*_feed.out.gz" && "c:\temp3\*_feed.out.gz" ^|findstr "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.'
) do if "%%F" geq "20130101" if "%%F" lss "20130902" echo 
do copy "c:\temp4\" %%F  
Please Suggest

Comment: Hi Can you please suggest on above further.